# VideoJS no flash backup

Tags: ios, flash

I would like to use VideoJS in my iOS app and web app therefore, I would like to include the videoJS library without the flash backup component.

Is it possible to not include flash backup and default to the message of

```
"NO HTML5 video supported"
```

on the web app if users use old browser or Firefox or IE7-?

Regards,
Duc Haba

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<video ... data-setup='{"techOrder":["html5"]}'` to prevent flash from being used. But you don't need to do that to use video.js on iOS - flash is only used as fallback where it is available.